# Server 2012 AD-DS Setup Fails (Microsoft.Directory.Services.Deployment.DeepTasks.DeepTasks not found)

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2012

I am currently trying to promote my 2012 Server to a Domain Controller but when I am at the first step in the setup I get the Error Message

(German, Original Message):

> [Bereitstellungskonfiguration] Fehler bei der Bestimmung, ob der
>   Zielserver bereits ein Domänencontroller ist: Der Typ
>   [Microsoft.Directory.Services.Deployment.DeepTasks.DeepTasks] wurde
>   nicht gefunden: Vergewissern Sie sich, dass die Assembly, die diesen
>   Typ enthält, geladen ist.

(Translated to English):

> Error while determining, if the Targetserver already is a Domain
>   Controller: The Type
>   [Microsoft.Directory.Services.Deployment.DeepTasks.DeepTasks] was not
>   found: Make sure, that the assembly, that contains this type, is
>   loaded.

Thus I can neither Configure the AD-DS nor deinstall them via Server Manager. Any Help how to fix that problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

"The server currently has IIS8, MySQL (both can not be removed), Sharepoint, TFS, and the Project 2012 Plugin. The Idea is to run an exchange server on this server and to run an exchange you need IIS, MsSQL and a DC."

That's definitely the wrongest possible approach to a domain controller, which should be this and nothing else.
Infrastructure roles (DNS, DHCP) are ok, but web services (and especialy SharePoint and Exchange, which assume to have full control of a the server) are totally *not* ok.

I strongly advise against installing all of this on a DC.

If you *really* want to go down this route, you should first promote the (empty) server to DC, and only later install anythjing else. Installing lots of things on a server and then attempt a DC promotion is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Well thanks, that question is 7 years old and if I am not mistaken, that Machine does not even exist anymore. Whereas your answer might still be a valid advice for other people, it does neither answer my initial question nor solve that problem in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a corrupted installation. It would be terribly useful if you gave us all the relevant information too, like this being a VM, and running Sharepoint, TFS and the Project Server on the same server. I'm not sure what you're trying to setup but a DC should not run anything else (DNS and arguably DHCP being exceptions).

Comment: Well then, that server is a 2012 Datacenter Server running on Hyper-V (alongside another 2012 installation which can not be used for features of this setup). 

The server currently has IIS8, MySQL (both can not be removed), Sharepoint, TFS, and the Project 2012 Plugin. The Idea is to run an exchange server on this server and to run an exchange you need IIS, MsSQL and a DC. As this server is in an internet envoironment I can not just make up another VM as i could on my local network (where I can NAT the virtual IP adresses to the physical network) as I dont have any left.